# Universal Link does not open app in ad hoc installable build

Tags: ios-universal-links, aasa

I have added universal link support for an app. The following are added

- aasa file is added at the root of the Website URL.
- The entitlements file contains the appropriate URL

When the device is connected and app is installed using Xcode in Debug mode, the Universal linking works (Tapping on a link present in Mail opens the app).

However, when the app is archived and installable is created, tapping on the link opens the app in Safari Browser instead of opening the installed app.

Am I missing any other detail specifically while creating an archived installable ?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved:

- Add the .entitlements file in the Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources option.
- While exporting validate that the entitlement for Associated Domain is available. If not, then turn the Capability On/Off, Close Xcode and reopen and then retry. Once it is available, then export the Archive.
- Lastly, set a valid path "/somepath" instead of simply "*" in the aasa file.

Making the above changes helped to get it working.